# Using custom message headers

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, wcf

I have an Application interface which contains:

```
string ApplicationName { get; set; }
string ApplicationId { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to add the above two parameters in the message header.

I have a HeaderInspector:

```
private IApplicationData ApplicationData{ get; set; }

    public HeaderInspector(IApplicationData appData)
    {
        ApplicationData= appData;
    }

public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        request.Headers.Add(new ApplicationHeader(ApplicationData));         
        return Guid.NewGuid();     
    }
```

What's the best way to include them in the OnWriteHeaderContents

```
protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {            
      //Tried using writer.WriteElementString("ApplicationName", "Name" );
    }
```

Note: Tried creating using the example: http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/calling-salesforce-soap-apis-from-a-net-core-or-uwp-app